# Increase range of motion on flat bench dumbbell chest fly

Tags: injury-prevention, range-of-motion

Are there any extra benefits, and is it safe to use increased range of motion in the stretched position of the chest fly movement?

I have found that while holding my arms straight out is fine, when I let me shoulders go all the way back with the dumbbells closer to the floor I get a better stretch and connection to my pecs. I know the queue push your chest and shoulders back can give you a bigger stretch, but I’m too the extent of my hands 3-4 inches off the ground. Also would a bend in my elbow help? Currently I do them mostly straight arm.

Just want to follow up with any info before I continue doing so in other sessions.

Comment: I’ve put this on hold for now, as it isn’t clear what you’re asking. Do you have a specific question about longer range of motion flies? A nonspecific request for more info is a bit too broad for our format here, but if you have particular concerns, we may be able to address those.

Comment: I have edited the post, please review.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are benefits to an increased range of motion as studies have shown that the 'stretch' of the muscle in a legthened position is beneficial to hypertrophy. You need to bend your elbow  though. Having straight arms is putting unnecessary stress on the elbows, increasing the risk of injury. It also causes more work for your biceps, eventually making them the limiting factor. Your arms can straighten at the top, allowing you to get your elbows close together and get a tight squeeze on your chest, but at the bottom, I'd say you want a 100-120° bend in your elbow.

Also, pulling your shoulders back and down (by contracting your traps and lats) is not only beneficial for ROM but is just proper form and should be used for all chest exercises.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot!